# Is it possible to have a UITableView with one row always in edit mode, showing its insertion or deletion control? If so, how?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with some data, and I'm hoping to put in the top row or section a cell (call it, "Add Record" or something), which is always in edit state, so that it always displays the system insertion control. Is this possible? If so, how?

I've searched all around for this. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623222-setediting) lists a `setEditing(_:animated:)` method on `UITableViewCell`. I used both that and setting `isEditing` to `true` on the cell on load, and it appears to be in `isEditing` state because the table wouldn't let it be selected until I turned on 'single selection in edit state'. But no insertion or deletion controls show up, and the delegate's `tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:)` is never called.

The cell looks fine if I call `setEditing(_:animated:)` on the table view itself, but that sets *every* cel to editing, deletion and all! That's not what I want.

I suppose I can just use a normal cell, and use an image of an insertion control, but I'd rather use Apple's system one if possible (since they might change). Aside: I could always load up an editing table on load and cache a snapshot of an editing control, but that's waaaay more work than its worth!

Is what I'm going for even possible? Do you understand what I'm going for? Any advice you could provide would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach:

1. Keep using `setEditing` on the `UITableView` itself.
2. To show the editing controls only for a specific cell, implement the 
   `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method of the
   `UITableViewDataSource` delegate and return true only for the cell that you wish to allow editing for.
3. At this point your specific cell will show the editing controls, but the cells are not selectable; you'll need to set `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` on your table-view
   to allow the cells to get selected. Next, you will probably want to
   prevent the editing cell from being highlighted by implementing
   `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` delegate method and return true for
   all cells except for the cell that you want to keep in editing mode.

Other possible solutions:

- Create your own `UITableViewCell` and implement the editing UI yourself (which will always be visible), then use this cell where you need it.
- Use another `UITableView` with a single cell which will always be in editing mode and place it above your other table so it would appear to be the same table. It's a possible solution **but most likely an overkill**.

Comment: I might use your first alternative solution.  I want to be able to edit the other rows as well, so `canEditRowAtIndexPath` will return true for most every row in the table anyway.

Comment: Do you know of a way to allow leading or trailing swipe actions work when editing is disabled for a row?  I would still like to be able to swipe my other rows, even though they don't have a delete button on the left.